# Error installing rgdal library in R :

Tags: dependencies, r

I am struggling with terra installation. To be complete, I tried every hints I have found in google, but nothing change this error message. I need rgdal as 'terra' dependency if I understand well, but I receive the same message when I try to install terra or rgdal. I have tried to uninstall, reinstall, install via pip, via conda, but nothing works. I am quite desperate.
gdal is installed via brew:
`gdal-config --version` gives `3.5.0`

Logs in R :

```
> install.packages("terra")
Installation du package dans ‘/home/col1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)
essai de l'URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/terra_1.5-34.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 667829 bytes (652 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 652 KB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** package ‘terra’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
** using staged installation
configure: CC: gcc
configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 3.5.0
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.1... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking gdal.h usability... yes
checking gdal.h presence... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... no
checking GDAL: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gdal/3.5.0_1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `opj_decoder_set_strict_mode'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gdal/3.5.0_1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gdal/3.5.0_1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `opj_encoder_set_extra_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gdal/3.5.0_1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/home/col1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  l'installation du package ‘terra’ a eu un statut de sortie non nul
Les packages source téléchargés sont dans
    ‘/tmp/RtmpaCYwto/downloaded_packages’
```

If anyone have a clue, I would really appreciate,

Comment: Can you ask the developers?  Indeed, something is missing and since you're compiling from source, the developers might be able to offer hints and suggestions for your particular system.  It might be that a particular version in a particular directory is needed, for example.

Comment: I have reported my error to the maintainer, I'll post his response, thank you!

Comment: I've manually reinstalled PROJ, GEOS and GDAL. Everything worked fine. However, when I try to install terra again, I get a new error :

free(): invalid pointer
./configure: line 3594: 26971 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./gdal_proj
no

I litteraly have no more options or ideas. I think the only way is to totally install and reinstall all these, or even reinstall ubuntu, but because it is a dual boot I am not sure I want to. I just don't understand how this can be so hard to install GDAL correctly, even from source, while I had NO problem on two others PC. Do you have an idea?